# Screws and anchor to install leaning Ikea cabinet into wall

Tags: screws, drywall-anchor

I live in the US and I am trying to buy wall anchors online for screwing a cabinet with only one row of legs onto a wall so it doesn't lean over. I should mention that the cabinets are from Ikea (https://www.ikea.com/us/en/p/mackapaer-shoe-storage-cabinet-white-50334751/) and there are holes already in the cabinet for installing into a wall. I just need to find the correct screw and anchors. The distance from the inside of the cabinet to the other side of the wall is about 1.5". The cabinet holes are about 28" apart so they cannot be both screwed into a stud.

For example, an anchor like this says is for #8 screws: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B08665MZ7M/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=A1LQDSIIXH5MHS&psc=1#customerReviews](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08665MZ7M)
And these anchors are #6 - #12:
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0051IAWM2/ref=ewc_pr_img_2?smid=A3RH26VT14A2VF&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0051IAWM2)

I couldn't find anything after hours of Googling. How do I know the exact #8 screw to buy? I've read that there are fine and coarse threaded screws with different threads per inch. Or should all, say #8 screws, be the same threads per inch unless specified otherwise?

Comment: Are these "base" cabinets (top ~ <1 m (~ <36 in)) above the floor OR are these tall cabinets (~ 2 m) above the floor? You say there is only one row of legs. Are the legs next to the wall or out into the room or in the middle or along one side of each unit? Please give a link to exactly the units you want to install.

Comment: Have you opened up the boxes and started to install these or are they still flat packed?

Comment: @JimStewart I already resolved this issue. I screwed one hole into a stud and one hole into an anchor.

Comment: That sounds like you arrived at a fully safe  and correct installation. Drywall can provide much more strength than some people realize . . .  with the appropriate anchors, but the best support is to screw into a stud. Very often one screw is into a stud and one into drywall. I assume you have wood studs in this structure. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I went with a hybrid approach since I can only align one hole to a stud. For the hole that cannot be aligned to a stud, I bought a pack #6-#10 of Hillman DuoPower anchors from Home Depot, which fit screws from #6 to #10. It looks something like the following but mine was a smaller package.
https://www.homedepot.com/p/Hillman-6-10-and-10-12-x-1-9-16-in-DuoPower-Contractor-Strength-Anchor-Kit-60-Pack-376476/302043755

It also came with the appropriate 1/4" drill bit for the anchors. I was afraid anchors like this wouldn't hold tightly and end up spinning, but that wasn't the case as I just drilled the hole and hammered the anchor in and the anchor could not budge at all as I screwed my screw in.

But instead of using the screws that came with the anchor, I used I these #10 cabinet screws from home depot:
https://www.homedepot.com/p/10-x-2-1-2-in-Zinc-Plated-Phillips-Drive-Truss-Head-Cabinet-Screw-with-White-Painted-Head-25-Piece-802972/204274998

I also used the same cabinet screw for the hole aligned to a stud, which I needed to buy a similarly long, about 2.5" long, drill bit that is 1/8" in diameter to drill a pilot hole.

This solution was satisfactory for my Ikea cabinet:
https://www.ikea.com/us/en/p/mackapaer-shoe-storage-cabinet-white-50334751/

This is because I am not hanging it, but rather the screw is to prevent the cabinet from sliding or tipping off it's one row of legs. So the total weight support required of the screws isn't that high since the cabinet is already somewhat stable leaning flush against the wall without even being screwed into the wall.

Answer (score 1):

You want wood screws(screws made to go into wood).

The fine and course threads you saw are for machine screws and bolts.  They need nuts or threaded holes.

For cabinets I would use #10 or #12 wood screws that go into the stud about an inch and a half.  You need to know the thickness of the cabinet back/support and add that to 1/2 inch for drywall.  Add those two measurements to an inch and a half into the stud.

Comment: The distance from the inside of the cabinet to the other side of the wall is about 1.5". My drywall seems to be 0.625". What do you mean by "add those two measurements to an inch and a half into the stud"? The holes in my cabinet is pre-drilled as they are Ikea cabinets, they just didn't come with screws to install into the wall.

Comment: @Dobob  1.5(cabinet) plus .625(drywall) plus another 1.25 0r 1.5 to go into the stud.  Electric wires and plumbing are supposed to be 1.5 inches from the stud edge or have a steel plate protecting them.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I don't think the section of the wall I am drilling into has a stud. it's a thinner section that comes out of the main walls. I tried using my stud-finder magnet and couldn't find any studs. This is why I am trying to get an anchor.

Comment: @Dobob  Drywall is not that good to hold heavy stuff, might be okay just add extra support from tipping over(self standing/on legs).  If not going into studs(recommended to use), then remove the length into the studs.

Comment: Actually, I tried using the stud finder again and found some studs, but the cabinet holes are not spaced correctly to screw both holes into a stud (holes are about 28" apart). So I think I will probably try and screw just one hole into a stud and leave the other one. I just need the cabinet not to tip. It's already sturdy leaning against the wall without screws.

Comment: Assuming the wall is drywall, and that the space the anchor is intended to go is wider than 16" (otherwise it's 99.9% there's a stud somewhere there), IMO the *best* anchor for drywall is a toggle bolt or toggle anchor.  To me, 2nd best would be the spiral type of anchor. What model Ikea cabinet is it?

Comment: @Huesmann This is the Ikea cabinet:
https://www.ikea.com/us/en/p/mackapaer-shoe-storage-cabinet-white-50334751/
It has weird 3 front legs but no back legs. The instructs asks you to screw it against the wall, but the screws are not provided and we have to buy the screw ourselves.

Comment: Gotcha.  Note that while Ikea may have provided holes for you, I don't think it's *required* to use those specific holes—you can make your own.  The thing is >30" wide, so there's *gotta* be a stud somewhere along the back.  Toss a cabinet screw, or other long wood-type screw into the stud, with a new hole you drill, and add a drywall/toggle anchor in the Ikea-provided hole that's furthest away.

Comment: @Huesmann The holes inside the cabinet are spaced around 28" apart, that's why only one of the holes can be drilled into a stud.

Comment: I'm sure the holes are basically nominal.  You should feel free to "roll your own" to fit your actual installation.

Answer (score 1):

Cabinet screws are what you need to use.  They are readily available on line and in most hardware & big box stores.

Cabinet screws have a wide head that prevents the screw from digging into the cabinet wood when you snug it up.  They need to be long enough to pass through the wood in the cabinet, the drywall, and into a wall stud.  Since you are not using the screws to hang the cabinet on the wall (like you would for a kitchen wall cabinet), you only need 1"-2" of penetration into the stud.  So a 2-1/2" or 3" screw should be long enough.

They look something like this.  Pic from Home Depot.
[image]

Comment: The wall I am installing on is a thinner section that comes out of the main wall. I tried using a magnetic stud finder, but I couldn't find any studs, so I assume there are no wood in the section of the wall I am installing the cabinet on. This is why I am trying to use an anchor.

Comment: Understand.  So if you don't have any wood behind the wall, these cabinet screws won't work.  Did you try tapping on the wall?

Comment: I looked for studs again with my magnetic stud finder and found the studs this time, but the pre-drilled holes in my cabinet are 28" apart, so it looks like I can only install one of the holes into a stud and the other still needs to be anchored to something.